# Variable scope issues

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I ran into a problem with global variables. It seems that trying to redeclare the variable as local changes its value in the whole scope, even for the previous uses.

EDIT: the problem is fixed. Both functions just show the before and after. And what I'm trying to figure is why does it change.

```js
variable = 1;
local_var_dec();
global_var_global();
 
function local_var_dec(){
    console.log("local: "+ variable);
    if(typeof variable === 'undefined'){
        var variable = 2;
    }
}
 
function global_var_global(){
    console.log("global: "+ variable);
    if(typeof variable === 'undefined'){
        variable = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use `var` and declare the variable in advance?

Comment: `var variable` on global.  try like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By having `var variable` inside your `local_var_dec`, you're *shadowing* the global with an entirely different *local* variable. That means the global isn't available within `local_var_dec`. And because `var` variables are *hoisted*, it's not available **anywhere** in `local_var_dec`, exactly as though it looked like this:

```
function local_var_dec(){
    var variable;                        // ***
    console.log("local: "+ variable);
    if(typeof variable === 'undefined'){
        variable = 2;                    // ***
    }
}
```

So that means when you assign to it, you're assigning to the **local** variable, not the global; doing that has no effect at all on the global, which is why when you call `global_var_global` later, you see the global's original value.

Although you can still access the global, you can't access it as a *variable*. Implicit globals¹ such as yours (and ones declared with `var` at global scope) are properties of the global object, and so can be accessed via the global object, which is accessible as `window` on browsers. So `window.variable` would access it within `local_var_dec` on browsers. In other environments, there may or may not be a global for the global object defined by the environment. On NodeJS for instance, there's `global`. You can always get a reference to the global object, though, from `this` at global scope (assuming the environment allows you to run code at global scope; NodeJS doesn't, for instance).

Fundamentally, though, avoid shadowing variables if you need to access them, since that feature of globals is A) Specific to globals, B) Not really a good idea, and C) Not available with the new `let` and `const` declarations.

Here's a snippet annotated with what exactly is happening, and showing using `window.variable` (although again, ideally just use a different name):

```js
// This creates an *implicit global* by assigning
// to an undeclared identifier
variable = 1;
local_var_dec();
global_var_global();
 
function local_var_dec(){
    // This shows `undefined` because `variable` in the below is the *local*
    // variable you've declared with `var`, even though the `var` hasn't
    // been reached yet. `var` is *hoisted* to the top of the function.
    console.log("local: "+ variable);
    // This is still the local, so it's still `undefined`
    if(typeof variable === 'undefined'){
        // This sets the *local* variable to 2; it has no effect at all on
        // the global
        var variable = 2;
    }
  
    // If you wanted, you could use `window.variable` here
    console.log("window.variable = " + window.variable);
}
 
function global_var_global(){
    // Because there's no `var` in this function, this us using the global
    // `variable`
    console.log("global: "+ variable);
    if(typeof variable === 'undefined'){
        variable = 2;
    }
}
```

---

¹ *Implicit global* - A global created without any declaration, by assigning to it. More in my blog post [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Comment: It should be noted that accessing the globals will be different in different contexts - ie `window.variable` won't work in Node for example, you'd need to access it with `global.variable`. Yay for subtle differences in Javascript!

Comment: @SyDy: I've flagged that up. Re the "yay": That's because that's not a difference in JavaScript. :-) JavaScript doesn't define `window` (or `global`). From [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-global-object): *"In addition to the properties defined in this specification the global object may have additional host defined properties. This may include a property whose value is the global object itself; for example, in the HTML document object model the window property of the global object is the global object itself."* Note the "may."

Comment: Oh, I understand that. It's just that the implementation of JS is necessarily inconsistent because it is defined solely by its spec and implemented in many different forms. In other words, the _mays_ of JS are fodder for easy confusion... just ask `this` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific with your question. This is quite obviously Javascript, even if you did not specify this. What output do you get from this script? Which browser type and version are you using?

About your question:
I would expect this console output:

```
local: 1
global: 1
```

Reason: the condition `if(typeof variable === 'undefined')` will be false in both function calls. Consider the function

```
function local_var_dec(){
    console.log("local: "+ variable);
    if(typeof variable === 'undefined'){
        var variable = 2;
    }
}
```

Where `var variable = 2;` is defined *after* this test for variable being undefined so `variable`  is truly local.

Besides; if you define a global variable without using `var` this variable becomes in fact a property of the `window`object, not a stand-alone Javascript variable. You might as well address it as `window.variable`, meaning that you could inadvertently modify a `window` property just by not using the `var` keyword.

Comment: The if statement does evaluate to true in the `local_var_dec` function. See T.J.'s excellent answer on hoisting below.

Comment: *"This is quite obviously Javascript, even if you did not specify this."* Yes, they did: They tagged the question with the [tag:javascript] tag, which is entirely sufficient.

Comment: *" the condition if(typeof variable === 'undefined') will be false in both function calls"* No, it won't. In `local_var_dec`, it's true -- for the reason I explain in my answer. You can also run the snippet in the question to see it.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `var` from line 8 and add it to first line (but not needed)

```js
var variable = 1; //add `var` here, not needed
local_var_dec();
global_var_global();
 
function local_var_dec(){
    console.log("local: "+ variable);
    if(typeof variable === 'undefined'){
        variable = 2; //remove `var` from here
    }
}
 
function global_var_global(){
    console.log("global: "+ variable);
    if(typeof variable === 'undefined'){
        variable = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Like @T.J.Crowder stated in the other answer: The `var` is not the problem. It's a matter of "implicit globals"...

Comment: ...but the question is "why does it change?" - not how to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

**Never declare a variable a variable without "var" if you wish to use it globally**,
Declaring it without "var" causes issue.
If you wish to use it locally may be you could do that but it is not a good practise.
So Solution is Add var to the very first line of code right before **variable**.
Ex:

```
var variable=1;
```

Then check the output.

Hope it helps<
Regards
Shohil

Comment: The lack of `var` isn't the problem with the OP's code. (It's *a* problem, but not the one the OP is asking about.) *(not my dv)*